# valgrind : invalid read of size 1 during strcpy

Tags: c++, valgrind

When I started valgrind, everything worked fine, but starting with this error, the lines that follows start to behaving the same (invalid read, etc).

```
Invalid read of size 1
==5134==    at 0x4C2BFE7: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5134==    by 0x40C553: XAMBO::listing_start(std::string&) (listing.cpp:616)
==5134==    by 0x40DAD7: msg_callback(unsigned char*) (msg_callback_act.cpp:263)
```

where the function of listing.cpp is as following (the function takes a string and remove comma, and put the result into an array. I pick randomly the result from the array, and put it in a string and return back 1 string result)

```
listing_start(string& _string){

           string pick, tkn;
           size_t pos = 0;
           string delimiter = ",";
      const char *service[MAX_SERVICE];

           int i= 0,random_val= 0;

        std::string::iterator e = std::remove(_string.begin(),_string.end(), ' ');
                _string.erase(e, _string.end());

        while ((pos = _string.find(delimiter))!= std::string::npos) {
            tkn = _string.substr(0, pos);
            if (!tkn.empty()) service[i] = tkn.c_str();
                i++;
             _string.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }           
    service[i] = _string.c_str();
    random_val = rand()%i;
    strcpy((char*)pick.c_str(), service[random_service]);
        return pick;
```

}

The line that valgrind points to is this : 
strcpy((char*)wanted_service.c_str(), service[random_service]);

I can not figure out why the stringcopy in the line above does not work as it should (although when I print the result, I have what I want). why is valgrind complaining, how should I fix the code above?

Comment: Why are you writing to the return of `c_str()`? This is explicitly not allowed!

Comment: `pick` is empty and you're trying to copy *into* it.

Comment: `strcpy((char*)pick.c_str(), service[random_service]);` is pretty wild! Personally, I wouldn't mess around with the internals of std::string. Why don't you just do `pick = service[random_service]`?

Comment: Replace `const char* service[MAX_SERVICE]` with `std::vector<std::string> service` and you'll have a much harder time creating problems. Don't forget to increment `i` after the `service[i] = _string.c_str();` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy((char*)pick.c_str(), service[random_service]);
```

It's incorrect. `pick` is empty string and string contents shouldn't be modified via `c_str`.
You should use

```
pick = service[random_service];
```

in this case.

```
if (!tkn.empty()) service[i] = tkn.c_str();
```

It's incorrect. After next `tkn = _string.substr(0, pos);` in `service[i]` will be next `tkn.c_str()` (in case, if there was no memory reallocation, otherwise you have dangling pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store results of `c_str` in the `service[i]`: `c_str` gets invalidated as soon as you make any modifications to the `string` from which you pulled the `c_str()`. If you must have a C string, make a copy with `strdup`; otherwise, use `std::string` to simplify your memory management.

In addition, using `c_str()` as a *destination* for `strcpy` is just wrong. The fact that you cast const-ness away with `(char*)pick.c_str()` should have been a clear indication to you that what you are doing is not correct. If you want to copy one string into the other, you can use the assignment operator instead.